# what is write failed, manual zeroing?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I am playing with my ubuntu VM (vmware), and I just got this message pop up in my conosle, what does it mean?

[image: Screenshot here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're affected by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-raring/+bug/1271430).

The best thing you can do is add yourself to the bug list so that you will be informed when the bug gets fixed.  In the mean time: it's just an annoyance...